# Using Inverse Kinematics and/or Pole Targets to move hair bones in unison?

Tags: armature, bones, hair, inverse-kinematics

I have a model whose hair is composed of several strands that I have each connected to a bone as part of the whole armature. What I want is for each "hair bone" to rotate at the tail in correspondence with the bone above her head (which I have unparanted). The goal is to use one bone to move all the other bones in unison so make it easier to bob her hair up and down as I animate her.

My first thought went to using that bone above her head as a Pole Target, but my understanding is that you need one IK bone for a pole target to work, and the thing is I have several "hair" bones, not just one.

What do I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some heavy research, I found that one simply can't assign multiple bones to a parent bone under the guise of copy rotation or any other such restraint option; it's a 1:1 bone ratio situation. But! Not to worry: I just created a few different bone groups, assigned each hair strand to a group according to its location on the head, and that did it. Still... I wish I could get the hair bones to rotate on its head instead of its base. It seems like I can do that but it'd take some wonky manipulation that doesn't seem worth the cost.

At any rate, this feels like a limitation Blender shouldn't have. I should be able to control multiple bones with one bone like a type of Pole Target bone without the inverse kinematics.

Answer (score 0):

For the hair to bob, subdivide all your strand bones and scale down the lower bone, this is your 'link' to the head. Use a damped track constraint on this bone, set their target bone to the strand bone (whatever you need to 'bob'), set the influence to around 0.5 (you can experiment with that), once you are happy with the movement on one strand just select all the others and click on copy to selected. It'll follow the movement to whataver its parented to, with a slight delay.

[image: here's the setup, try moving around the head to see it working]